# "Excel has stopped working" when using VBA macro with on change event

Tags: excel, onchange, vba

I am experiencing a consistent "Excel has stopped working" error. I have a user form that populates a combo box with dependent drop-down options based on what the user selects in the 1st combo box.

The error is **consistently** created for **ANY** of my on-change event subs when the user types into the 2nd combo box a letter that corresponds with an existing value that should be in the 2nd box. If the user selects an option from the drop-down list, it does not occur -- only when the user types in the 1st letter of a matching value.

Example: If 1st combo box is "Fruit", 2nd combo options might be "Apple", "Orange", etc.  If the user types in "A" or "O" in the 2nd box (because it matches corresponding values), it crashes Excel.  Why does it not simply "fill in" the matching value like it does on the 1st combo box?

Error handling is in place, but it never throws this error in code, only "excel has stopped working", then crash.

**Do I need to use enable/disable worksheet events within the macros? If so, please offer a suggestion of how to implement and explanation of how it works.**  I have solved previous On Change problems by simply converting them to a click button, but I'd rather learn how to better implement On Change events without errors.

Thank you!  Here is some example code that I think is associated with the Excel crash:

```js
Private Sub Option1_Change()

On Error GoTo Option1_Change_Error
'Set cell H4 as value entered in Opt1 (adv. filter criteria)
Sheet6.Range("H4").Value = Me.Option1.Value
'Run macro AdvFilter which sets criteria for dependent drop-down box
AdvFilter
   Me.Option2.Value = ""
'Set row source as output of adv filter
Me.Option2.RowSource = "AdvFilter_Output"
'Set list box content
'If no adv.filter output, then blank listbox
If Sheet2.Range("BZ3").Value = "" Then
    Me.lstOptions.RowSource = ""
Else
    Me.lstOptions.RowSource = "AdvFilter_Output"
End If
Exit Sub

Option1_Change_Error:
MsgBox "An error has occurred.  " _
    & vbCrLf & "" _
    & vbCrLf & "" _
    & "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Option1_Change_Error of Form frmOptions"
End Sub




Private Sub Option2_Change()

On Error GoTo Option2_Change_Error
If Me.Option1 = "" And Me.Option2 <> "" Then
    MsgBox "Select a the category first to see the corresponding options that exist."
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Me.Option2.RowSource = ""
End If
Exit Sub

Option2_Change_Error:
MsgBox "An error has occurred.  " _
    & vbCrLf & "" _
    & vbCrLf & "" _
    & "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Option2_Change_Error of Form frmOptions"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you walked through this code with a debugger? Which line does it choke on? If you haven't already, I'd strongly suggest whacking a breakpoint on the first line of the function and then stepping through the code line-by-line to understand what is breaking it. It'll also tell you if it's even this code that's breaking it - if thee breakpoint never trips (but excel still crashes), it could be something else entirely.

Comment: First thought, though: what is `AdvFilter_Output`? And do you assign a named range to a rowsource like that? I'd have expected RowSource to take a Range...

Comment: @tobriand Thanks for your response. AdvFilter_Output is a dynamic named range that holds the output data of an advanced filter. It populates a listbox automatically when the user fills in the 1st combo box as a visual aid to show users what options are already present in the records for the category they selected. AdvFilter_Output also becomes the rowsource for the 2nd combo box based on what the user selects in the 1st combo box. Could you clarify your second question about the named range and rowsource?

Comment: Usually when I assign to fields for things like `RowSource`s (for instance in defining names), I find that if I'm not careful, it ends up assigning a string instead of the entity I want it to, which obviously doesn't work. I'm basically wondering if something like that is happening. If that's the case, changing it for `"=AdvFilter_Output"` might do the job (it'll explicitly realise you mean the name then).

Comment: Other thought, now you said Dynamic Named Range, is Scope. It's conceivable that it's a worksheet scoped name but it's looking to the workbook or vice versa. Would be bizarre for that to make it crash Excel, though...

Comment: @tobriand I am not sure the issue is with the dynamic named range, as it is correctly populating the secondary combo box with the appropriate values in the drop-down list, so that must mean it is finding the range OK. The scope of the dynamic named range is set to workbook -- I did [previously have that issue on some other ones, where it was set to only worksheet, but all are workbook currently. The problem comes in when the user tries to manually type in a value. I will follow your suggestion to debug it line by line and see if it spits out anything.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks to being able to bounce off some ideas with Tobriand and run through some possible problems.  **The problem ended up being conflicting rowsource between the two events, as a result of an inappropriate `else` clause within Option2.**

`Private Sub Option2_Change()` was setting the `Rowsource` for the second combo box as blank on `change`, preventing the ability to type in anything. The `match entry` property was set to False, but I assume the removal of the rowsource for combobox 2 caused the `match entry complete` property to freak out when a user typed in something and it didn't find a match. **I removed the `else` portion from the Option2 event and it seems to work now.**

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted! Auto-completion always struck me as a little lightweight in Excel; sounds like it's another of those useful-until-it-isn't features. The order of execution must be change --> your-event --> their event then, I imagine. I can see why that makes logical sense, but really highlights the shortcomings of VBA in handling native errors, doesn't it?